# a xml is converted it to df. The columns consists of lists and dictionaries of different dtype. Unable to append and sort a list

Tags: pandas, xml, list, dataframe, sorting

```
    df = pd.json_normalize(parseredDict,sep='_')
    Title_list=[]
    Title_list.append(df['ArticleTitle'])
    print(Title_list)
    print(Title_list.tolist())
```

Output looks like this.

```
     Name: Publisher_Journal_Volume_Issue_Article_ArticleInfo_ArticleTitle, dtype: object]
     [0    Involvement of P-Glycoprotein .........
     Name: ArticleTitle, dtype: object]
     [0    The Complexities ........
     Name: ArticleTitle, dtype: object]
     [0    Efflux .....
     Name: ArticleTitle, dtype: object]
     [0    Isolation ...
     Name: ArticleTitle, dtype: object]
     [Series([], Name: ArticleTitle, dtype: int64)]
        ######################
     [[['Enhancement of ......', 'Amélioration de ......']]]
     [['Functional .....']]
     [['Involvement of ....']]
     [['The Complexities ......']]
```

I am unable to append them in one list and then sort alphabetically. the dtype of this column is obj and int64.Appending to one list is not working. Please help

Comment: Where is the XML in this question? I see `json` handling being used.